# "represent ... by" expression to describe a graph axis

Tags: prepositions, verbs

Please consider the following sentence:

> The bar graph **represents** literacy rates **by** country in 1990 and 2000
>   across six different countries for men and women.

Does using "represents ... by" to describe one of the graph axes sound natural? I have not see such a structure before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, **by** has nothing to do with **represents**. It explains how the figures are divided into categories. In the same way, one could say

> The salary figures in the report are grouped **by** department.

See section 3.3 of the definition of **by** from the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/by).